# Do you know any Augmented Reality library for python?

Tags: python, augmented-reality

I would like to code something with augmented reality, do you know any python library to play with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) would be the closest match I can think of ...

Comment: +1 Uhm, probably the only available way to AR with Python.

Answer (score 1):

ARToolKit apparently has python bindings:
http://www.hitlabnz.org/forum/showthread.php?548-PyARTK-0.1-Python-binding-for-ARToolKit-released

I've not experimented, ymmv.